# Tornado datetime

Tags: python, datetime, offset, tornado

How would I create a datetime stamp from a clients offset? I have been messing around with this all day. The idea is to have a user login and based upon their timezone to create the cookie to expire after so long.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tornado.auth
import tornado.database
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import tornado.escape
import hashlib
import unicodedata
import markdown
import os.path
import re
import urllib
import sys
import time
import json
import MySQLdb
import Cookie
from tornado.options import define, options
import datetime
from nptime import nptime

define("port", default=8001, help="Server port", type=int)
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
            (r"/test", Test),
        ]
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers)

        self.db = tornado.database.Connection(
            host=options.mysql_host, database=options.mysql_database,
            user=options.mysql_user, password=options.mysql_password)

class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @property
    def db(self):
        return self.application.db

class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.set_header("Content-Type", "text/html")
        self.write()
        self.finish()

class Test(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        tmz = self.get_argument('tmz', '')
        cur = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p 'tmz, gmtime())
        self.set_header("Content-Type", "text/html")
        self.write(cur)
        self.finish()

def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Where tmz would be the timezone sent example -0400 or +0500

Answer (score 0):

You could have a hidden datetime input pass the client's current time, including timezone, into the login form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="current_datetime" />
```

That input's value can be populated with javascript.

Then, in your post function, you can add hours or days to the value that current_datetime passes in.

Comment: That would be a possibility except that when if the user has been on the page for awhile idle, i.e. got up to do somethings and came back, than the amount of time would be short lived. Doesn't seem like this should be to hard to accomplish, as when running it as a script from the server its fine, its running it through the web that seems to be the problem, Tornado seems to kick a 500 error

Comment: I ended up figuring out the problem. For some reason it needed to be put within `int()`